SLAM Toolbox map size too small
I am working out of a simple 4 walled gazebo world with a 2 wheel differential drive robot similar in size to the turtlebot3. I am using the nav2_bringup package to launch the nav2 nodes and the slam toolbox so I can map the environment around the robot. However, the issue is that the initial map size made by slam toolbox is too small. What i mean by this is that somehow the slam toolbox node detects the four walls around the robot, and generates a map exactly the size of those 4 walls. Two of the walls correclty show up on the occupancy grid, but the other 2 walls do not show up in the occupancy grid because they are considered out of bounds. Thus, these walls do not show up in the global costmap used by nav2. Interestingly though, the walls show up in the local costmap. I am not sure how to configure the initial map size so that its big enough for all the walls to render in.
As a workaround, if I move the robot using gazebo controls to some location outside the room and then move it back into the room, the map is resized in slam toolbox and then the walls will show up on the occupancy grid.
I am looking for suggestions on how I can force the map to become larger so I dont have this issue.
